# Multiple colors in highchart's Contour graph

Tags: highcharts, colors, heatmap, contour

I have a requirement in my project where i need to create contour chart using High charts,I have successfully created the chart with the data but now i need to define the legends color as per my data values,as of now the color combination is taken care by the high charts implicitly but i want to use specific color for a specific value.

Basically in my chart i am representing the variation(Percentage difference) in prices b/n two days for two categories so lets say if the the price shoots up the color will be red and if there is price fall the color will be blue,but in order to show the smooth transition between the prices i am using different shades for blue and red and want to associate these color based on their values.

is there is any way where i can do the above customization in code so that i can get the chart like this

### Please guide

Can I add multiple colors in Contour ?
Just guide me for the same.

If yes what I have to use ?

---

I am uploading two images of my graph, both representing same data.
1 is of **Heatmap** and 2nd is of **Contour**.
Heatmap
[Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHTEi.jpg)

and
Contour
[Contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BNuo.jpg)

Heatmap is representing the colors as I coded, but the moment I convert Heatmap to Contour, the colors are not setting properly.

Please guide me can I convert Heatmap to Contour in terms of colors exactly same ?

Comment: Could you recreate your example as live demo ?

Comment: Could you post your example (Contour) as live on jsfiddle.net?